# Python HTTP Requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

The following figure shows the TMDb endpoint documentation by which a client can request a movie or TV show be added to a user's watchlist, where the user has previously established a session_id.

Based on the developer documentation, and using the (fictional) values of the various pieces that need to be part of the request and that are presented in the following table:

[image]

**Question !!**
Can you please provide the HTTP for this request? You can present the request in a line-oriented fashion, and without needing to note linefeeds or carriage returns.

[image]

Comment: are you asking us to write code for you or are you asking for how to structure a http request

Comment: Code would be better like as a set of steps in Python. Thanks!

Comment: Things dont work like this here, What have you tried? Here Community wants you to learn something but if you have not put in any efforts to learn that, how will that help you out?

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about writing code, the following lines could be useful for you:

```
import requests

account_id = 12345
url = 'https://YOUR_URL.com/accout/' + account_id + '/watchlist'
payload = {'media_type': 'movie', 'media_id': 777, 'watchlist': 'true'}

x = requests.post(url, data = payload)

print(x.text)
```

Where is:

```
requests.post(url, data={key: value}, json={key: value} -> string, args)
```